# two player turn based game android

Tags: java, android, http, sockets, multiplayer

I want to make a two player turn based game (think of tic tac toe) for android. I am not sure how to implement the communication between the mobile and the server. Should I use sockets or http client ? Can anybody guide.
Issue with http client is I have to regularly poll the server to see if any data has arrived. Is there any other way to push the data from server if I am using http client ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered HTTP requests + [push notifications](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/)? Depending on the particular kind of game this might be the best solution I guess...

Comment: is this how other multiplayer game sdeveloped, say draw something etc ? also, will the push notification not make game slow ?

Comment: @alexandrucristescu if you are already making HTTP requests why bother with push notifications?  Their delivery is not even guaranteed and you can get the information immediately via the http requests.

Comment: @MikeIsrael because you would have to poll your server at regular intervals otherwise. Depending on the nature of the game, doing that rarely enough to not flood your server might be too slow. Perhaps this question is a bit too open-ended?

Comment: @AlexandruCristescu yeah I would say more than a bit.  Out of curiosity have you ever implemented a system like the one you recommended?  I am curious about the response time of the C2DM messages.

Comment: Sorry guys for the question being very open ended, I have modified it somewhat, thanks for input.

Comment: issue with c2dm is that it is not reliable, they have mentioned it on the introduction. Is there any way to push the data yourself ?

Comment: @JohnWatson if you keep open a tcp connection you could push data objects.

Comment: @MikeIsrael what disadvantages it has got ?

Comment: @MikeIsrael no, not in a production environment. I have played around with it and it worked well, but not under stress...

Comment: @AlexandruCristescu thanks for the input, good to know for future products.

Answer (score 0):

You can use App Engine's Channel API

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/

Even though there is no official Android library you can use this WebView wrapper

https://github.com/burcu/android-channel-api

but I haven't tested it yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but if you are still looking for a solution you could try the new [Google Play  Game Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/).