# Android Turn Based Game Multiplayer Suggestion

Tags: android, multiplayer

I am making a very simple Android turn based game its UI will be like this.

[image: UI Image]

**Game Concept:**

- Two player game.
- Each user place his turn to make the winning sequence.

I want to make this game multiplayer. I'd like a simple solution, as I only need to send the button position to the other user.

I've looked at these things: Stackmob, Parse, Kinvey, AppEngine, [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734774/two-player-turn-based-game-android?rq=1),
but they all look more difficult than I had hoped. What is the simplest way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your game would be playable on 2 devices at a time, you have 2 options to sync both instances of game.

1) Using **Bluetooth** (A good example is given in android API examples ie **Bluetooth chat**)

2) Using **WiFi** (its very very simple, just like a client server communication)

You may encode / decode state in **base64** string so it could be transfer quickly.

**EDIT:**

Here is a good example about using wifi for communication:

http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/

Comment: thanks for reply
Please kindly can u explain more about using wifi and gave some good client server communication link..??

Comment: kindly tell me does it will work worldwide networks mean we just need server ip address to connect with or it will work only on same wifi network??

Comment: It would work locally. Perhaps if you want to let it work you need an intermediate live server.

Comment: thankx it really helped me.thats the solution i am looking for..

Comment: Sorry there was a word missing in my previous comment: It would work locally. Perhaps if you want to let it work worldwide you need an intermediate live server.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Google Play Games Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/). It provides API's for finding opponents and sending messages between participants in a multiplayer match.

With platforms like Kinvey or AppEngine you would have to do a lot of backend programming, with the Google service you don't need to do any server-side programming.